# remove attribute by using getelementbyclass

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here i am trying to call class and get the value in variable to remove its attribute **style** and setting **style** again but it shows error like this

> Uncaught TypeError: cls.removeAttribute is not a function.

```
cls = document.getElementsByClassName("ps-scrollbar-x-rail");
cls1 = document.getElementsByClassName("ps-scrollbar-x");
cls2 = document.getElementsByClassName("ps-scrollbar-y-rail");
//alert(cls);
//alert(cls1);
//alert(cls2);
//console.log(cls);
//console.log(cls1);
//console.log(cls2);

cls.removeAttribute("style"); 
cls1.removeAttribute("style");
cls2.removeAttribute("style");

cls.setAttribute("style","width: 600px; left: 258px; bottom: 1px;"); 
cls1.setAttribute("style","left: 143px; width: 333px;");
cls2.setAttribute("style","top: 0px; right: -255px;");
```

Onclick to call this method. Which shows error.

Answer (score 5):

`getElementsByClassName` will return to you an `array like object` - `NodeList` . You need to call `removeAttribute` on each item of that object. You can iteraet over it using simple `for` loop or `foreach()`

```
for(var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++){
   cls[i].removeAttribute("style"); 
}
```

**Examples**

With **For**

```js
var cls = document.getElementsByClassName('text');

for(var i = 0; i < cls.length; i++) {
   cls[i].removeAttribute('style');
}
```

```html
<p style="color: red" class="text">Test</p>
<p style="color: red" class="text">Test</p>
<p style="color: red" class="text">Test</p>
<p style="color: red" class="text">Test</p>
```

With **ForEach**

```js
var cls = document.getElementsByClassName('text');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(cls, (item) => item.removeAttribute('style'));
```

```html
<p style="color: red" class="text">Test</p>
<p style="color: red" class="text">Test</p>
<p style="color: red" class="text">Test</p>
<p style="color: red" class="text">Test</p>
```

Comment: Obvious duplicates don't need answers, they need close votes.

Comment: yes but my classes are different not the same as you see above

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript gets the elements as an array. You need to use

```
cls[0].removeAttribute("style"); 
cls1[0].removeAttribute("style");
cls2[0].removeAttribute("style");
```

Comment: error shown Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null

Answer (score 0):

Given that `getElementsByClass()` returns a live NodeList, you have to iterate over each of the elements in that NodeList in order to remove the attribute from each Node in turn.

But given that you're looking for the elements of three individual classes, it would make more sense to use `document.querySelectorAll()`, which allows for multiple selectors and then iterate over each element in the returned (non-live) NodeList:

```
// retrieves a non-live NodeList of all elements with any
// of the specified class-names:
var allClasses = document.querySelectorAll('ps-scrollbar-x-rail, ps-scrollbar-y-rail, ps-scrollbar-x');

// uses Array.from() to convert the Array-like NodeList
// into an Array:
Array.from( allClasses )

  // upon which we can use Array.prototype.forEach():
  .forEach(

    // using an Arrow function to call
    // Element.removeAttribute() on
    // each element in turn; 'el' is
    // the current element in the Array
    // of elements:
    el => el.removeAttribute('style')

  );
```

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Element.prototype.removeAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute).